# problem: Applying Well-Ordering Principle to prove a fact

Tags: induction

problem: Prove the fact using WOP: every amount of postage that can be assembled using only 10 cent and 15 cent stamps is divisible by 5.

The problem provides a template for this proof and asks that we fill in the remainders after a the ellipsis.

I got through the first part of the proof:

Let C be the set of counterexamples namely C: = {n | ...S(n) and NOT 5 |n}, where S(n) returns T/F depending on whether the amount of postage can be assembled using 10 cents and 15 cents stamps. *Note 5 | n means that n is divisible by 5.

Assume for the purpose of obtain a contradiction that C is nonempty. By WOP there must be a least element m. This m > 0 because...it is assumed that the amount of postage n > 0.

But if S(m) holds and m is positive, then S(m-10) or S(m-15) must hold because...

The above statement is confusing me. For example S(25) holds because m > 0 and is comprised of one 10 cents AND one 15 cents. However, would S(25-10) or S(25-15) hold? I believe these wouldn't hold since S(15) and S(10) cannot each be comprised of 10 cent AND  15 cent multiples.

Hope my question makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't mean that you must use at least one 10-cent stamp and at least one 15-cent stamp: it means that you're allowed to use 10-cent stamps and you're allowed to use 15-cent stamps, and you're not allowed to use any other sorts of stamps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $S(15)$ should return true because $15 = 0 \cdot 10 + 1 \cdot 15$. Note that $0$ is a $10$-cent multiple.

Now since $m > 0$, we know that this counterexample must either contain at least one $10$-cent stamp or at least one $15$-cent stamp. If the former occurs, then we know that $m - 10$ can also be assembled using (at least zero) $10$-cent stamps and (at least zero) $15$-cent stamps. If the latter occurs, then we know that $m - 15$ can also be assembled using (at least zero) $10$-cent stamps and (at least zero) $15$-cent stamps. So $S(m - 10)$ or $S(m - 15)$ must return true. But notice that since $5$ doesn't divide $m$, it also won't divide $m - 10$ or $m - 15$ (since $10$ and $15$ are multiples of $5$). Thus, $m - 10$ or $m - 15$ belong to $C$, contradicting the minimality of $m$ (as desired).

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I follow, esp. your statement: "If the former occurs, then we know that m−10 can also be assembled using (at least zero) 10-cent stamps and (at least zero) 15-cent stamps. If the latter occurs, then we know that m−15 can also be assembled using (at least zero) 10-cent stamps and (at least zero) 15-cent stamps." Say m = 15, then S(15) = True. But shouldn't S(5) or S(0) return False since neither of those values can be assembled from 10 or 15 cents? Otherwise for any number n S(n) will always return True which doesn't make sense...

Comment: Think of the argument like this. Suppose that $m \in C$ so that $S(m)$ returns true and $m$ is not divisible by $5$. Now since $S(m)$ returns true, we know that $m \geq 0$ (since $m$ can be assembled using $x$ $10$-cent stamps and $y$ $15$-cent stamps, where $x,y \geq 0$). But since $5 \mid 0$, we know that $m \neq 0$ so that $m \geq 1$. Hence, either $x \geq 1$ or $y \geq 1$. In other words, $m$ can be assembled with at least one stamp. Removing this stamp doesn't change the fact that it will still belong to $C$.

Comment: That makes sense. But can you explain why S(0) holds?

Comment: After this step the template continues: "So suppose S(m-10) holds. Then 5 | (m-10) because if 5 | (m-10) weren't true, it would be a smaller counterexample than m, contradicting the minimality of m. Then it continues that if 5 | (m-10), then 5 | m because if 5 | (m-10), then obviously 5 | m. I don't really get the last statement. Instead I wrote that since m is a linear combination of 10 and 15, 10 and 15 share common factor of 5. Therefore 5 | m. Does this work?

Comment: $S(0)$ holds true because $0 = 0 \cdot 10 + 0 \cdot 15$. They are using the fact that since $5 \mid (m - 10)$ and since $5 \mid 10$, we know that $5$ divides their sum so that $5 \mid m$. That is, $m$ is a linear combination of $m - 10$ and $10$. What you wrote was a direct proof that avoids the Well-Ordering Principle altogether.

Comment: @Adriano I have real difficulties with proving things by WOP. The theorems are very easy statements, but the logical deduction is really hard. I guess to large part, this is due to general difficulty with proof by contradiction as stated [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40753-021-00152-x). Do you have any suggestions how one could come up with the statements like yours?